# How can I change the position of map controls after initialization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, maps

I want to change the position of the mapcontrols after the map has been initialized.

I am able to change visibility using

```
map.set('streetViewControl', false);
map.set('streetViewControl', true);
```

but I am not able to move the controls from left to right.

thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Use `map.setOptions` to change each controls position, after the map is initialized.

Example, move the zoom control to top right, *after* initialization :

```js
function zoomControlToRight() {
    map.setOptions({ zoomControlOptions: { position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT } });
}
```

Just pass a valid chunk of a mapOptions object, what you want to change, to `setOptions`. To move the street control, pass

```js
streetViewControlOptions: {
   position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
}
```

instead. Demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9VYjA/**

See [**modifying controls**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlModification)  and look for setOptions [**here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Map).